# Why last element is called "remove"

Tags: javascript, django, json

I am beginning with django.

I am using a json in my javascript:

```
views.py:
a = ModelA.objects.filter(status = 'A').values('name', 'id', 'pos', 'status')
b = ModelA.objects.filter(status = 'B').values('name', 'id', 'pos', 'status')
data = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

I am working with [nodeshot](https://github.com/ninuxorg/nodeshot), where there is a function to get the json:

```
$.getJSON(nodeshot.url.index+"nodes.json", function(data) {
        nodeshot.nodes = data;
    });
```

but when I do this:

```
var data = nodeshot.nodes[status];         //'a' for example
for(var node in data) {
...
}
```

If I do `alert(node)` I get:

```
0
1
remove
```

What is this `remove` ?
This loop should pass only 2 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're iterating over the property names of the list object you got. This contains the element indexes but also the names of the enumerable functions.

Don't. Iterate as on arrays.

Replace

```
for(var node in data) {
```

with

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   var node=data[i];
```

Comment: It works, thanks!!.How can I see the functions ?I mean,I use `toSource()` to see the properties.Is there anything to see the functions ?

Comment: You can for example log `data[node]`, or do `console.dir(data.constructor.prototype)`. But looking at the source or documentation of the library you use might be simpler.